# mysql - Unknown Column In Where Clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Following Sql query throws error

> 1054 - Unknown column 'registered_user_detail.user_id' in 'where clause'

Query:

```
SELECT
  `user_feedback`.`user_id`,
  `user_feedback`.`feedback_status`,
  `registered_user_detail`.`user_id`
FROM
  `user_feedback`,
  `registered_user_detail`
WHERE
  `registered_user_detail.user_id` = `user_feedback.user_id` AND `user_feedback.feedback_status` = 1
ORDER BY
  `user_feedback.feedback_id`
DESC
```

I have both "user_feedback" table and "registered_user_detail" table; also the "user_id" column in both table. Then what's going wrong.

Comment: Your query specifies table and field as `\`user_feedback.user_id\``, where it should be `\`user_feedback\`.\`user_id\`` (same for all other tables and fields)

Comment: @Da  How I made this type of error ?? However, many many thanx Damir Kasipovic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the punctuationmark symbol in where clause,correct use is: (punchmark)tablename(punchmark).(punchmark)columnname(punchmark). Please try with this:

SELECT
  `user_feedback`.`user_id`,
  `user_feedback`.`feedback_status`,
  `registered_user_detail`.`user_id`
FROM
  `user_feedback`,
  `registered_user_detail`
WHERE
  `registered_user_detail`.`user_id` = `user_feedback`.`user_id` 
  AND `user_feedback`.`feedback_status` = 1
ORDER BY
  `user_feedback`.`feedback_id`
DESC

Comment: thanx for your great answer. query is running greatly, but just tell me, what is the difference in ur query with my query, bcoz both looks SAME. What's wrong with my query ?

Comment: In your query,you used punctuation mark wrongly. After the WHERE condition you have to use punchuation mark as 
(punchmark)registered_user_detail(punchmark).(punchmark)user_id(punchmark).

But you did as (punchmark)registered_user_detail.user_id(punchmark). That is the mistake in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Use correct `JOIN`'s and consistent back ticks.

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.feedback_status, r.user_id
FROM user_feedback u
INNER JOIN registered_user_detail r ON u.user_id = r.user_id
WHERE u.feedback_status = 1
ORDER BY u.feedback_id DESC
```

Comment: or, better, no backticks at all - as in the example above

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for your reply, and your query is running just like 'rockzzzz'.  kindly explain me why my query is not executing, that was also a joining.